# Data storage for time series data

Tags: time-series, bigdata, query-performance

I have some scientific measurement data which should be permanently stored in a data store of some sort.

I am looking for a way to store measurements from 100 000 sensors with measurement data accumulating over years to around 1 000 000 measurements per sensor. Each sensor produces a reading once every minute or less frequently. Thus the data flow is not very large (around 200 measurements per second in the complete system). The sensors are not synchronized.

The data itself comes as a stream of triplets: [timestamp] [sensor #] [value], where everything can be represented as a 32-bit value.

In the simplest form this stream would be stored as-is into a single three-column table. Then the query would be:

```
SELECT timestamp,value 
  FROM Data 
  WHERE sensor=12345 AND timestamp BETWEEN '2013-04-15' AND '2013-05-12'
  ORDER BY timestamp
```

Unfortunately, with row-based DBMSs this will give a very poor performance, as the data mass is large, and the data we want is dispersed almost evenly into it. (Trying to pick a few hundred thousand records from billions of records.) What I need performance-wise is a reasonable response time for human consumption (the data will be graphed for a user), i.e. a few seconds plus data transfer.

Another approach would be to store the data from one sensor into one table. Then the query would become:

```
SELECT timestamp,value 
  FROM Data12345 
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2013-04-15' AND '2013-05-12'
  ORDER BY timestamp
```

This would give a good read performance, as the result would be a number of consecutive rows from a relatively small (usually less than a million rows) table.

However, the RDBMS should have 100 000 tables which are used within a few minutes. This does not seem to be possible with the common systems. On the other hand, RDBMS does not seem to be the right tool, as there are no relations in the data.

I have been able to demonstrate that a single server can cope with the load by using the following mickeymouse system:

1. Each sensor has its own file in the file system.
2. When a piece of data arrives, its file is opened, the data is appended, and the file is closed.
3. Queries open the respective file, find the starting and ending points of the data, and read everything in between.

Very few lines of code. The performance depends on the system (storage type, file system, OS), but there do not seem to be any big obstacles.

However, if I go down this road, I end up writing my own code for partitioning, backing up, moving older data deeper down in the storage (cloud), etc. Then it sounds like rolling my own DBMS, which sounds like reinventing the wheel (again).

Is there a standard way of storing the type of data I have? Some clever NoSQL trick?

Comment: Yes, this is not really a SO question, but it is interesting.  Check out all the other sites on http://stackexchange.com/sites ,  such as perhaps "Programmers" or "Computer Science".  I would say what you want is very high-performance.  You could do it with a "vanilla" system like SQL Server or Oracle.  But your speed goals are tough. 1 billion rows out in 3 seconds == massive processing power & fancy hardware and logical parallelism.  Cloud systems will also be too slow over the wire.  If you can give up some speed it isn't so tough since the simple data structure helps, as you already know.

Comment: I tried to paraphrase the question to describe the problem more clearly. The output bandwidth is not a problem, as I only need to get a moderate amount of data from one sensor at a time. Typical queries would return maybe 20 000 data points. No fancy hardware is needed - at least preliminary benchmarks suggest that this can be done with a single server.

Comment: Nice.  In that case your implementation is probably more important than which system.  Data architecture is always the key :).  Have fun!

Comment: @DrV: did you solve the problem ? What dbms according to your opinion is best suited for these types of problems ?

Comment: @DrV Here's a quick and dirty solution. How about streaming your sensor readings to some queue like Kafka, and then have 1 or more workers dumping the data to parquet files? The parquet files are easily queryable from powerbi etc?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a pretty easy problem really. 100 billion records, 12 bytes per record -> 1.2TB this isn't even a large volume for modern HDDs. In LMDB I would consider using a subDB per sensor. Then your key/value is just 32 bit timestamp/32 bit sensor reading, and all of your data retrievals will be simple range scans on the key. You can easily retrieve on the order of 50M records/sec with LMDB. (See the SkyDB guys doing just that https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/skydb/CMKQSLf2WAw/zBO1X35alxcJ)

Comment: Thank you for your expert opinion! I do like the way LMDB is done, and I have been thinking of using it in this application, but I did not come to think of using subDBs. I do admit my ignorance regarding them and have to ask if there is a difference in using, say, 500 databases with 200 subDBs each or 1 database and 100 000 subDBs? (The 50 000 000 records/sec is truly impressive, but unfortunately my data is going to be on a disk, so my worry is the number of random pages read or written.)

Comment: LMDB is a single-writer design, so you would consider splitting into 500 databases in order to support 500 concurrent writers. Aside from that, there's a question of how many subDBs must be open simultaneously - the initial mdb_dbi_open() actually does a linear search in the table of open DBIs so it may be slow for 100,000. (But this also may not matter, since open only needs to be done once per run.) Aside from that no real perf difference.

Comment: InfluxDB is a time series database that can use LMDB http://influxdb.com/blog/2014/06/20/leveldb_vs_rocksdb_vs_hyperleveldb_vs_lmdb_performance.html

Using LMDB's Sorted Duplicates feature can save some space and time as well, see my comments to their post.

Answer (score -1):

Try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) as a time series database for big amounts of data.

- It is optimized for storing and querying big amounts of time series data.
- It uses low disk iops and bandwidth thanks to [the storage design](https://medium.com/@valyala/how-victoriametrics-makes-instant-snapshots-for-multi-terabyte-time-series-data-e1f3fb0e0282) based on LSM trees, so it can work quite well on HDD instead of SSD.
- It has good compression ratio, so 100 billion typical data points would require less than 100 GB of HDD storage. Read [technical details on data compression](https://medium.com/faun/victoriametrics-achieving-better-compression-for-time-series-data-than-gorilla-317bc1f95932).